# Writing split-on

Tags: scheme, racket, split

I tried writing the (what I found to be) immensely useful `splitOn` from Haskell in Racket (Scheme). I ended up with what follows, and it doesn't quite work. By which I mean, it just runs and eats up my memory. `take-until` and `drop-until` both work, so what am I doing wrong exactly in `split-on`?

```
(define (split-on lst pred)
  (cons (take-until lst pred) (split-on (drop-until lst pred) pred)))

(define (take-until lst pred)
  (take lst (- (length lst)
               (if (memf pred lst)
                   (length (memf pred lst))
                   0)))) 

(define (drop-until lst pred)
  (drop lst (length (take-until lst pred))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I wasn't dropping the delimiting character, making it loop forever.

```
(define (split-on lst pred)
  (cons (take-until lst pred) (if (not (null? (drop-until lst pred)))
                                  (split-on (cdr (drop-until lst pred)) pred)
                                  '())))
```

Comment: Note that your code has a bunch of inefficiencies, like taking the length of the list multiple times, using the same `memf` call twice, etc.  Also, this code could be better if Racket had things like `drop-until` etc in `racket/list`.  (This is planned to happen "soon"...)

Comment: Yeah, I know the code is ugly, lots of repeated calls. I'm working on fixing it now, I just had to get the logic down first.